# PhoenixOutputFormat not found when running a Spark Job on CDH 5.4 with Phoenix 4.5

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, apache-phoenix

I managed to configure Phoenix 4.5 on Cloudera CDH 5.4 by recompiling the source code. `sqlline.py` works well, but there are problems with spark.

```
spark-submit --class my.JobRunner \
--master yarn --deploy-mode client \
--jars `ls -dm /myapp/lib/* | tr -d ' \r\n'` \
/myapp/mainjar.jar
```

The `/myapp/lib` folders contains the phoenix core lib, which contains class `org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.PhoenixOutputFormat`. But it seems that the driver/executor cannot see it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.PhoenixOutputFormat not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getOutputFormatClass(JobContextImpl.java:232)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:971)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:903)
    at org.apache.phoenix.spark.ProductRDDFunctions.saveToPhoenix(ProductRDDFunctions.scala:51)
    at com.mypackage.save(DAOImpl.scala:41)
    at com.mypackage.ProtoStreamingJob.execute(ProtoStreamingJob.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.mypackage.SparkApplication.sparkRun(SparkApplication.scala:95)
    at com.mypackage.SparkApplication$delayedInit$body.apply(SparkApplication.scala:112)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at com.mypackage.SparkApplication.main(SparkApplication.scala:15)
    at com.mypackage.ProtoStreamingJobRunner.main(ProtoStreamingJob.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.PhoenixOutputFormat not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2018)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2110)
    ... 30 more
```

What can I do to overcome this exception?

Comment: How are you building mainjar.jar exactly?

Comment: You're in a much better position to answer this than anyone on Stack Overflow. Check your parameters: what ends up in `--jar`? Check the jars: do they contain this class? Use `rdd.foreach` to print the classpath on the executors. Does it contain the jar? This problem needs debugging, a bounty cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `phoenix-core` to classpath.txt solves the problem. This file is usually located under /etc/spark/conf folder.